# The eigen values of Johansen's cointegration procedure

Tags: time-series, cointegration, eigenvalues, vector-error-correction-model

Assume a K dimension VECM model for cointegration analysis

$$\Delta y_t=\Pi y_{t-1}+\Gamma_1\Delta y_{t-1}+...+\Gamma_{p-1}\Delta y_{t-p+1}+u_t$$

The Johansen approach for maximum eigenvalue test or trace test or maximum likelihood estimation, all requires the eignen values $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k$ of some matrix. For example, the maximum eigenvalue test statistic for $H_0:rk(\Pi)=r$ is
$$-T\ln(1-\lambda_{r+1})$$

My question is: Which matrix are these eigen values $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_k$ calculated from?

I've roughly read Johensen's original paper and some other advanced books about cointegration. They say the eigen values are calculated from
$$S_{11}^{-1/2}S_{10}S_{00}^{-1}S_{01}S_{11}^{-1/2}$$
I won't give the precise definition for this matrix. If you've read one of those stuff, you should know what I'm talking about.

However, in some intruductory time series books, the authors say that the eigen values are calculated from the estimate of $\Pi$
$$\hat{\Pi}$$
Those books are, for example, *Applied Econometric Time Series* by Walter Enders, and *Time Series Econometrics* by John D. Levendis.

So I can think of 3 possibilities.

1. The two matrices are the same.
   $$\hat{\Pi}=S_{11}^{-1/2}S_{10}S_{00}^{-1}S_{01}S_{11}^{-1/2}$$
2. The two matrices are not the same, but somehow they have the same eigen values.
3. The authors of intruductory time series books are wrong or oversimplify.

So can anyone tell me which is it?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is it isn't 1 or 2. $\Pi=\alpha\beta$ is an error correction matrix. There is at least one cointegrating relationship if $\Pi$ is non-zero and has reduced rank. To the extent $\Pi$ has reduced rank $r$, the $\beta$ is a matrix containing the cointegrating relations, or normalized cointegrating vectors which yield stationary linear combinations of the variables in the system.

To estimate $\beta$, you need to minimize an error covariance matrix from auxiliary (concentrated) regressions by solving the following eigenvalue problem: $|(1-\rho)S_{11}-S_{10}S_{00}^{-1}S_{01}|=0$, where $1-\rho=\lambda$ is the eigenvalues you want to calculate. The $\lambda$'s are squared canonical correlations. The larger the $\lambda$, the more likely it is that the corresponding eigenvector is a stationary linear combination.